# Ansible - Write variable to config file

Tags: ansible

We have some redis configurations that only differs on port and maxmemory settings, so I'm looking for a way to write a 'base' config file for redis and then replace the port and maxmemory variables.

Can I do that with Ansible?

Comment: I've found this way; http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/replace_module.html but I'm not sure if the best way to do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such operations usually [`lineinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) module works best; for example:

```
- name: Ensure maxmemory is set to 2 MB
  lineinfile:
    dest: /path/to/redis.conf
    regexp: maxmemory
    line: maxmemory 2mb
```

---

Or change multiple lines in one task with `with_items`:

```
- name: Ensure Redis parameters are configured
  lineinfile:
    dest: /path/to/redis.conf
    regexp: "{{ item.line_to_match }}"
    line: "{{ item.line_to_configure }}"
  with_items:
    - { line_to_match: "line_to_match", line_to_configure: "maxmemory 2mb" }
    - { line_to_match: "port", line_to_configure: "port 4096" }
```

---

Or if you want to create a base config, write it in Jinja2 and use a [`template`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html) module:

```
vars:
  redis_maxmemory: 2mb
  redis_port: 4096

tasks:
  - name: Ensure Redis is configured
    template:
      src: redis.conf.j2
      dest: /path/to/redis.conf
```

with `redis.conf.j2` containing:

```
maxmemory {{ redis_maxmemory }}
port {{ redis_port }}
```

Comment: Wow! Great answer, I'll give a try! Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The best way i've found to do this (and i use the same technique everywhere)
is to create a [role](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#roles) `redis` with a default vars file and then override the vars when you call the role.

So in `roles/redis/default/main.yml` :

```
redis_bind: 127.0.0.1
redis_memory: 2GB
redis_port: 1337
```

And in your playbook :

```
- name: Provision redis node
  hosts: redis1

  roles:
    - redis:
      redis_port: 9999
      redis_memory: 4GB

- name: Provision redis node
  hosts: redis2

  roles:
    - redis:
      redis_port: 8888
      redis_memory: 8GB
```

Comment: And when you **create** a role, you don't need to define any task/module, right? How does it even remotely answer the question? Or maybe you meant: the easiest is to find a ready-made solution on GitHub/Galaxy, not to bother how things work, not to ask questions on SO?

Comment: @techraf OP asks how he can create a base config for redis and that's what i answer. OP didn't ask for the task implementation.

Comment: "*Write variable to **config file***"; "*write a 'base' **config file** for redis and then replace the port and maxmemory variables*"; "*I've found **this way**; `replace_module`*"